# database design. how to design one table has 10 relationship with same one dictionary table

Tags: database-design

I have a question about database design.
For example,I have one dictionary table named "User",
and have another data table named "OperationInfo",the data table has multiple column is referenced to "User",
like

```
User:              OperationInfo:             
+-----+------+     +-----+------------- +------------- +------------- +------------- +...
| Id* | Name*|     | Id* | CreateUserId*| UpdateUserId*| RemoveUserId*| DeleteUserId*|...
+----------- +     +-----+------------- +------------- +------------- +------------- +...
| 1   | Jack |     | 1   | 1            | 2            | 2            | 1            |...
| 2   | Tom  |     | 2   | 1            | 1            | 1            | 2            |...
+-----+----- +     +-----+------------- +------------- +------------- +------------- +...
```

If i want get all user names,i have to join multiple times,
like

```
 SELECT B1.Name AS CreateUserName
       ,B2.Name AS UpdateUserName
       ,B3.Name AS RemoveUserName
       ,B4.Name AS DeleteUserName
       ,... 
   FROM OperationInfo A 
   JOIN User B1 ON A.CreateUserId = B1.Id
   JOIN User B2 ON A.UpdateUserId = B2.Id
   JOIN User B3 ON A.RemoveUserId = B3.Id
   JOIN User B4 ON A.DeleteUserId = B4.Id
   JOIN ...
```

Multiple times Join just for get names, This is not good,because this data table has **more than ten** foreign key with user table.
I have a solution is store user name in data table,
like

```
OperationInfo:             
+-----+------------ +------------- +------------ +------------- +------------ +------------- +...
| Id* |CreateUserId*|CreateUserName|UpdateUserId*|UpdateUserName|RemoveOperId*|RemoveUserName|...
+-----+------------ +------------- +------------ +------------- +------------ +------------- +...
| 1   | 1           | Jack         | 2           | Tom          | 2           | Tom          |...
| 2   | 1           | Jack         | 1           | Jack         | 2           | Tom          |...
+-----+------------ +------------- +------------ +------------- +------------ +------------- +...
```

then query all user names like

```
 SELECT A.CreateUserName
       ,A.UpdateUserName
       ,A.RemoveUserName
       ,A.DeleteUserName
       ,... 
   FROM OperationInfo A 
   <Condition>
```

query becomes much simpler.but this is not good,data redundant, will cause the name of the dictionary table and the data table to be inconsistent.
Is there any better design?  because there have a lot of redundancy column.
Should i do? very thx.

Comment: I don't understand what the specifications are.  Please elaborate on the specifications.

Comment: You don't say what you want. "What should I do" to accomplish what? Say what makes a design acceptable. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Also "better" doesn't mean anything until you define it with enough details that everyone would agree on a valuation. (In other words it's useless.) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284) Clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [help]

Comment: @philipxy What I want to express is that my problem is that I want to query all user names
I have two ways to solve the problem of multiple references. The first is to store the primary key and find out all the names by association.
The second is to use redundant fields to store user names, which eliminates the need to use a related query, but this will cause the name of the dictionary table and the data table to be inconsistent.
I do n’t want to know which answer A or answer B is better. I want to know if there is a better design besides these two.

Comment: "Clarify via edits, not comments."  PS Re clarity, the problme doesn't have much to do with whether this post is suitable or SO, because it just isn't clear. It's not suitable for humans. Also re finding "the answer" elsewhere, it's not clear what the question is. Suppose you gave someone this post. They couldn't come back with something that you know would solve your problem. The post doesn't say what your problem is. What is given, what may change, what must not change, and what properties is a response required to have, like some code that is supposed to have what properties?

Comment: Your comment is not clear. "Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean."

Comment: @philipxy I re-edited this question, I don’t know if it was stated clearly.thx.

Comment: So what if you have many joins? That's how the relational model works. Why are you worried? How is "not good" actually justified? You can have (userid, name) as FK to UNIQUE for consistency. But you must update in pairs. You can have oi(id, userid, role); with an index over all columns this is minimal join effort. But then you must constrain that there is every role per id. PS This is a much clearer post. But observe that we can't tell you what's "best"--just too many variable & it's chaotically dependent on them. You must measure & demonstrate with your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question...

Using multiple joins in Objectively better, because doing it the other way may cause the data to become stale, for example if a users name changes or that user is deleted... If you don't care about that for some reason, then go ahead and use the denormalized way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should normalize more.

Your User table is fine

```
User
----
User ID
User Name
```

You should also create an Operation table.

```
Operation
---------
Operation ID
Operation Name
```

Finally, you create a UserOperation junction table, since a user can perform many operations and an operation can be performed by many users.

```
UserOperation
-------------
UserOperation ID
User ID
Operation ID
```

Where you have a unique index on (User ID, Operation ID).  You can also have a unique index on (Operation ID, User ID).

Yes, your UserOperation table will have many rows, up to 10 rows per user in your problem description.  But this normalized solution can grow to 20, 50, 100 different operations per user.

Comment: I think the same as you,I have refactored my project like this,very thx.